# how to cache image using ionic angular mobile app?

Tags: angularjs, caching, ionic-framework

I have home page it contains with list of 2 images i have given controller and Html code.every time home page images loading from backend i want to cache the image in local to avoid every time http request and weekly once or 10 days once i want to check from backend if backend image has changed that time i need to update this cache image . i have followed some example but i could not solve this because i am new to this technology some one help me out to move forward

```js
.controller('TestCtrl', [
    '$scope', '$http', '$location', '$window', '$ionicLoading',
    function($scope, $http, $location, $window, $ionicLoading) {
        
        $scope.find = function() {
      $http.get('****').success(function(data, status, headers, config, response) {
                
                $scope.image1 = data[0].Images1;
                $scope.image2 = data[1].Images2;
                
            })
        }
           
    }
])
//console i am getting image1:http://res.cloudinary.com/dl34322/image/upload/q_58/v1437810617/store1.png image2:http://res.cloudinary.com/dl34322/image/upload/q_58/v1437810617/store2.png
```

```html
<ion-view  title="Home" data-ng-controller="TestCtrl" data-ng-init="find()"> 
<ion-content>

<div class="list card">
  <div class="item item-image">
     <img src="{{image1}}">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="list card">
  <div class="item item-image">
     <img src="{{image2}}" >
  </div>
</div>
</ion-content> 
</ion-view >
```

Comment: Just use standard HTTP headers to cache static content

Comment: sorry i could't get u what ur trying to say

Comment: @reptilicus Can yo please be more specific? maybe show an example code?

Answer (score 3):

Try using `ng-src` instead of `src` in `<img>` elements as shown below:

```
 <ion-view  title="Home" data-ng-controller="TestCtrl" data-ng-init="find()">   
    <ion-content>

    <div class="list card">
      <div class="item item-image">
         <img ng-src="{{image1}}">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list card">
      <div class="item item-image">
         <img ng-src="{{image2}}" >
      </div>
    </div>
    </ion-content> 
    </ion-view >
```

Comment: Please call out what changes you've made to the code. It's hard to see at a glance that you've used `ng-src`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$ImageCacheFactory` to cache images once and load it from cache when you need to load that again. 
Full documentation [here](https://github.com/andrewmcgivery/ionic-ion-imageCacheFactory)